# Create Early Bound Entity Classes

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create an object of account entity. below is the sample code, which i need to achieve.

```
Account earlyAccount = new Account();
earlyAccount.Name = "Early Bound Account";
Guid earlyAccountId = service.Create(earlyAccount);
```

To use "Account" as entity, what i need to do ? Do i need to import any other namespace?

Comment: You should add more details to your question. EG. What is actually going wrong? What have you done?

Answer (score 3):

In order to generate Early Bound classes you need to use the CrmSvcUtil.exe included inside the CRM SDK.

However I strongly suggest to use the [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator) available inside the [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/), it has several options to generate the classes and you don't need to deal with the command line.

Comment: Yes. i have seen that tool, but i don't know how to use it. Is there any link available to guide on that step by step ?

Comment: in the first link I provided there is a link to a video tutorial

Comment: hmm... that video is showing everything being based on codeplex... maybe I should update it?

Comment: maybe you can add some rectangles with text in your video with some links? I saw some youtube videos doing in that way when they need to warn the user about some content.

Comment: @Daryl but now the tool can be downloaded from the plugin store so maybe is better a new video

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in MS-DOS/Developer Command Prompt for VS20xx

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://serverName/organizationName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:outputFilename.cs /username:username> /password:password /domain:domainName
```